# How can I set the rotation of a shape to the same as my image?

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, slick

The way you set rotations of images is different from setting shape rotations.
So how can I make the shape have the same rotation as my image?

This is how my image rotates:

```
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT))
        {
            rotate += rotateSpeed * delta;
            image.rotate(rotate - image.getRotation());
        }
```

How can I get the same effect but with a shape?

For example:

[image]

How can I get that rectangle to be at the same rotation as the car?

Comment: Shouldn't you be rotating the complete sprite and not just the image? Otherwise couldn't you just set the rectangles rotation to that of your image?

Comment: Well the thing is the way you rotate the shape is different to the way you rotate the shape. The shape, you give it a number and it adds it to the current rotation. The image you give it a number say 90 and it sets the rotation to 90.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Slick2D to create the rectangle. Slick2D has a [Shape](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Shape.html) class that can be used to describe such things (rectangles, circles, etc.).

I imagine you're using a shape like this for collision because it has methods like `intersect()`([link](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Shape.html#intersects%28org.newdawn.slick.geom.Shape%29)) that allow you to detect such things.

`Shape` also has a nice method called `transform()`([link](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Shape.html#transform%28org.newdawn.slick.geom.Transform%29)). It can be used to apply a transform to your shape. Transforms are essentially matrix operations. Luckily you don't need to know too much about the matrix operation because it's easy to create transforms. `Transform` has a static method called `createRotateTransform`. You can use this to specify a rotation to create a transform to apply to the shape.

So the short of it would be, use something like this:

```
rotatedCarShape = carShape.transform(Transform.createRotateTransform(radiansToRotate)));
```

Remember that `transform` does not alter the original shape, so you don't have to worry about the rotations adding up, but you do need to remember to draw the correct transformed shape.

Comment: This is what I was doing but it wasn't working, it was not rotating at the same speed as the car. Then I realized that the shape transform need radians not degrees.

Comment: Ah, way ahead of me then. Hopefully it's working now.